# Select a range of data from active cell to specified cell in a different column

Tags: vba, excel

How do you select a range that contains data from the row below an active cell (or row) to a specified cell in a different column?

For example, if row 7 is selected (or cell A7), I want to select all of the cells (or rows) with data from A8 to BA200.

Answer (score 0):

The Macro will always select 200 rows below the `Activecell` and 52 columns across

You can obviously change the parameters(i.e 200,52)

```
Sub Picker()
 Range(ActiveCell.Offset(200 - ActiveCell.Row, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(1, 52)).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will select all the cells in the specified span relative to the starting cell if they contain data (or any other criteria you want).

```
Private Sub selectRangeWithData()

Dim startCell As Range
Dim dataRange As Range
Dim rowSpan As Integer, colSpan As Integer

Set startCell = Range("A7")
rowSpan = 200
colSpan = 52

'initialize the first cell of the selected range
Set dataRange = Range(startCell.Offset(1, 0).Address)

'loop through the supplied range and determine if data exists
For Each cell In Range(startCell.Offset(1, 0), startCell.Offset(rowSpan, colSpan)).Cells
    If cell <> "" Then
        'if so, add it to the range
        Set dataRange = Union(dataRange, Range(cell.Address))
    End If
Next cell
'finally, select the range of cells
dataRange.Select

End Sub
```